# Is there a way to clone the code with a SSH Key when using generic git connection for Azure Dev Ops Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Looks like the only way is with a user/pass which is not a way that we would like to do it. We'd prefer cloning the repo over SSH. Anyway this can be done? Or does Azure DevOps support extending it so we can develop our own plugin for GitAuthentication?

Or any idea where we can do feature requests for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of this page you can find this:

> **What protocols can the build agent use with Git?**
>
> The agent supports HTTPS.
>
> The agent does not yet support SSH

You can create a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html):

[image]